How can I get automatic code indexing of expl3 in ltxdoc?
How can I get correct automatic indexing of expl3 code in the ltxdoc class? Even better would be if the solution worked with xindy, but makeindex seems the only live option for documentation.
Example dtx/ins file pair:
exp.ins:
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askonceonly

\generate{\file{exp.sty}{\from{exp.dtx}{sty}}}

\endbatchfile

exp.dtx:
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{exp.dtx}[2024-07-26 v0.0]
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{exp}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{exp.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \pagestyle{empty}
% The answer you seek is 42\index{forty-two=\textsf{42}>answer>life, universe, everything}.
% Example\index{index entries>Special macros for \*}
%
% \MaybeStop{%
% \PrintIndex
% }
%
% \iffalse
%<*sty>
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{exp.sty}[2021-07-26 v0.0]
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g__test_rm_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \g__test_rm_tl {ybv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\g__test_rm_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%    \end{macrocode}
% \iffalse
%</sty>
% \fi
%\Finale


Note that I'm aware that l3doc will correctly index expl3 code. However, I would prefer to avoid using it in many cases because it has disadvantages of its own. Out-of-the-box, it garbles entries added with \index:

This can be worked around, but it is also necessary to work around out-of-the-box incompatibility with svn-prov. Moreover, I have some documentation which makes heavy use of \@writeindex for customisation, which is fine with ltxdoc but a problem for l3doc. (I also have some documentation which indexes expl3 and is incompatible with version 3 of doc.) Finally, I'd rather not use something which could change completely at the drop of a hat, since the updated version of doc already causes enough compatibility headaches for me to be getting on with.
My current solution is to not document my code at all, but only write user documentation with a mix of semi-automatic and manual indexing, but this isn't exactly ideal*.
Related posts:

How to document a expl3 macro using dtx on expl3 and ltxdoc with much earlier versions.

Three answers: one uses l3doc, one does nothing (or I'm applying it wrongly) and one breaks everything (not wholly surprised, but maybe I misunderstood).
I note that Joseph's answer advocates expl3 code be documented with l3doc and says L3 want to encourage this. But that was more than a decade ago and the current documentation puts l3doc firmly in the Here-There-Be-Dragons category.


Indexing when using the l3doc class on the problem of indexing terms directly when using l3doc.

One answer with two workarounds, either of which might work but would not support documentation currently using ltxdoc or address other issues with l3doc and look really highly likely to break even without the proximity of Dangerous Mythical Beasts.



*I don't think anybody else is interested, but it would make my life a lot easier if I could produce a code index.

Had a look at it this morning; and having given it enough thought, the conclusion is to rather use l3doc. For what is worth I am posting an answer.

According to the doc documentation, you can redefine \MakePrivateLetters so that it also sets the underscore (_) and colon (:) as “letter” characters. This is what doc itself does for its documentation:
doc.dtx:3253–3256
% \def\MakePrivateLetters{%
%    \makeatletter
%    \catcode`\_11
%    \catcode`\:11}

You can't just use \ExplSyntaxOn here though since doc needs \endlinechar to be a newline for it to typeset the source code properly. So a complete solution is the following:
exp.dtx
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{exp.dtx}[2024-07-26 v0.0]
\def\MakePrivateLetters{\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn\endlinechar13}
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{exp}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{exp.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \pagestyle{empty}
% The answer you seek is 42\index{forty-two=\textsf{42}>answer>life, universe, everything}.
% Example\index{index entries>Special macros for \*}
%
% \MaybeStop{%
% \PrintIndex
% }
%
% \iffalse
%<*sty>
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{exp.sty}[2021-07-26 v0.0]
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g__test_rm_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \g__test_rm_tl {ybv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\g__test_rm_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%    \end{macrocode}
% \iffalse
%</sty>
% \fi
%\Finale

exp.ins
unchanged
Output

Edit [cfr]
The solution above is great in many cases but causes compilation errors in others. To partially resolve this, I use
\def\MyMakePrivateLetters{\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn\endlinechar13}

before my \ProvidesFile line at the top of the .dtx.
At the end of the preamble, I add
\let\OrigMakePrivateLetters\MakePrivateLetters 

I can then switch to the modified definition using
\let\MakePrivateLetters\MyMakePrivateLetters 

and revert the modifications with
\let\MakePrivateLetters\OrigMakePrivateLetters

This is necessary, in particular, before some etx and mtx files, which otherwise cause compilation errors.
The modified definition also removes ~ characters from source listings, so I think ideally this might also be undone - either locally or, possibly, in the definition of \MyMakePrivateLetters.

The beauty of the l3doc is the presorting it does with l3 functions and variables, so your G \g__test_rm_tl  would be sorted under module test and NOT the letter G. This is not a major issue for commands like \cs as you can give it an option for the sorting class, but on the cross referencing of macros in macrocode . For user documentation only  doc provides a new command \NewDocElement  etc... so is half-way there.  Personally I forked l3doc  and did a lot of changes to overcome this and other issues.

@cfr You also don't have to use docstrip for TeX macro files. I can't stand docstrip, so I usually just write plain text comments inline in the source or parse the comments into ConTeXt buffers and typeset them there.

@cfr Where are you putting the \def\MakePrivateLetters{…}, before or after \documentclass{ltxdoc}? If it's currently before, then try after; and if it's currently after, then try before.

@cfr Put this after the \Provides Package....   \ExplSyntaxOn \cs_gset:Npn \MakePrivateLetters   {     \char_set_catcode_letter:N \@     \char_set_catcode_letter:N \_     \char_set_catcode_letter:N \:   }   \ExplSyntaxOff

@ok  I understand

@cfr You have way more experience with (l3)doc than I do, so it's probably easiest for you to edit that into the answer yourself. Or, if you prefer, you can write a new answer.

I've edited it in. I'd prefer it to be noted in the accepted answer rather than somewhere in the depths of zero-rated answers ;). there's also a less serious complication which I note, but this doesn't cause compilation failures so is much less critical. I think we should clean up a bit?

actually @yannisl's suggestion above might be better. either than or reverting the change to ~ caused by \ExplSyntaxOn.

Some comments:
1.0 If you are going to document any l3 layer code, you are better off to use
the l3doc class. Main advantages:a) follows the conventions and recommendations of the LaTeX Team. b) \cs,\cmd,``tn`, the two former are breakable.
2.0 There disadvantages: a) Too opiniated, but has to be, like any class used for a specific purpose it needs to enforce style.
The code below just provides a couple of extra commands for indexing. It will be better to save them under a style file cfr-l3doc-extras or similar.
Personally like I mentioned in different posts and comments, I forked the l3doc code into a different class to meet some more requirements that I had. I wanted to add colour and also be able to use any subclass, not just article. So far so good and I now use it for all my documents either they have or don't have l3 macros. The code I provide below leaves the l3docas is. They are just supplementary macros.
Like many I don't like writing much within % part extensively. So for an extensive user manual or something else. I add my-user-manual.tex.
In general ltxdoc, doc and l3doc break the principle of composability. But it is what it is. doc and l3doc should be packages only, with the sole purpose to define documentation commands only. In that case a user could use any base class they want. ltxdoc could then only use one of these packages or both if need be (it does more).
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{exp.dtx}[2024-07-26 v0.0]
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{exp}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{exp.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \pagestyle{empty}
% The seek is _42\Index[term]{forty-two=\textsf{42}>answer>life, universe, everything}.
% \DescribeTopic{Topics}
% ^^AExample\Index{index entries>Special macros for \*}
% \docColor{blue}
% 
% \MaybeStop{%
% \PrintIndex
% }
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*sty>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage{exp}{2021-07-26}{A hybrid (cfr)}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \DescribeMacro{\MakePrivateLetters}
%   A few more letters are \enquote{private} in a \LaTeX3 programming
%   environment.
%
% \DescribeMacro{\Index} a command for all practical purposes defaults
% to the original \cs{index}. 
%    \begin{macrocode}
% 
% \RequirePackage{xcolor}
% 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:Npn \MakePrivateLetters
  {
    \char_set_catcode_letter:N \@
    \char_set_catcode_letter:N \_
    \char_set_catcode_letter:N \:
  }
  \RequirePackage{ulem}
%    \end{macrocode}
% 
% 
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g__test_rm_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \g__test_rm_tl {ybv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\g__test_rm_tl}
\def\my@macro{legacy macro}

\NewDocElement[macrolike = false ,
         toplevel  = true,
                idxtype   =  topics,
                %idxgroup  = Ships,
                printtype = \textit{topic},
               ]{Topic}{topic}   
               
 \long\def\topic#1{#1\texttt{#1}}       

\newcommand\@ywrindex[1]{%   
\protected@write\@indexfile{}%   
{\string\indexentry{#1}{\thepage}}%   
\endgroup   \@esphack} 
\def\yindex{\@bsphack\begingroup \@sanitize\@ywrindex}
\cs_if_exist:cTF{uwave}
  { \def\term#1{{\uwave{\textbf{#1}}}} }
  { \def\term#1{  \textbf{#1}  }       }
  
  \DeclareDocumentCommand\Index{O{term}m}
{
  \yindex{#2 \encapchar hdpindex{#1}}
}

%    \begin{macrocode} 
  \DeclareDocumentCommand{\docColor}{O{term}m}
 {
  \fboxsep=3.5pt\fboxrule=0pt 
   { \color{#2}\bfseries\ttfamily  #2}\thinspace\fcolorbox{#2}{#2}{}
  
  
  \yindex{\string #2 (color) \actualchar{#2 \colorbox{#2}%
  {\phantom{\rule{10pt}{10pt}}}\thinspace(\textit{color})}\encapchar hdpindex{#1}}
  
\yindex{Colors:\levelchar#2\encapchar hdpindex{usage}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\def\mathcommand#1{
\yindex{Math Greek Symbols:\levelchar#1\actualchar\protect\textbackslash#1$(\csname#1\endcsname)$\encapchar hdpindex{term} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_math_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_math_clist{alpha,beta,gamma}
\def\Module#1{$\langle\fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{lc}\mbox{\color{red}#1}\rangle$}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \mathcommand{gamma} \tn{gamma}\cs{gamma}\cmd{\gamma}
% \mathcommand{delta} 
% 
%    \begin{macrocode} 
%</sty>
%    \end{macrocode} 
%\Finale


Thank you! agree completely about user manuals, though I still tend to use ltxdoc, just with separate .tex. I guess forking is also preferable since you are not then dependent on l3doc when it changes ;).

just to say that doc is a separate package which you can use with any class, so I don't think it can be accused of breaking composability. (is that a word?) and ltxdoc doesn't do much more, as I understand it, than add doc. l3doc is completely different. (but doc has some oddities of its own - at least it doesn't work as I'd expect, given the documentation.)

@cfr  Composability is a system design principle that deals with the inter-relationships of components. A highly composable system provides components that can be selected and assembled in various combinations to satisfy specific user requirements. doc-v3 broke this, plus it is too coupled to ltxdoc in many respects. But is almost there.

but you say doc should be a package, which it already is?
